# trying to pass parameter to php server from android app

Tags: php, android, http, get

my problem is this: I want do call a url in an android app and by this way give my webserver parameters in the uri like

```
myserver.com/index.php?name=peter&age=22
```

parameters are:

name=peter

age=22

the server is already running but i cant access it with my android app code...
and yes i have the permission in the manifest...

checked if i'm online...

Thanks for your help.

```
                try{
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    String getURL = "irgendeinurl.web44.net/index.php?vorname=maria asdf&email=me@mail.com&phone=0786655962&time=1500&date=160914&merk=wollte nachfragen wegem Termin :) tschüss";
                    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
                    HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);
                    HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();
                if (resEntityGet != null) {
                    //connection success
                    Log.i("GET RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet));
                }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

This is I get:

02-07 14:04:44.062: I/online?(27169): true
02-07 14:04:44.072: W/System.err(27169): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=irgendeinurl.web44.net/index.php
02-07 14:04:44.072: W/System.err(27169):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
02-07 14:04:44.072: W/System.err(27169):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
02-07 14:04:44.072: W/System.err(27169):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-07 14:04:44.072: W/System.err(27169):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-07 14:04:44.072: W/System.err(27169):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-07 14:04:44.082: W/System.err(27169):    at ch.mzg.app.Termin3$2.onClick(Termin3.java:106)
02-07 14:04:44.082: W/System.err(27169):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
02-07 14:04:44.082: W/System.err(27169):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
02-07 14:04:44.082: W/System.err(27169):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-07 14:04:44.082: W/System.err(27169):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-07 14:04:44.082: W/System.err(27169):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 14:04:44.092: W/System.err(27169):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4482)
02-07 14:04:44.092: W/System.err(27169):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 14:04:44.092: W/System.err(27169):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-07 14:04:44.092: W/System.err(27169):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
02-07 14:04:44.092: W/System.err(27169):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
02-07 14:04:44.092: W/System.err(27169):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: are you getting any error?Please post log here

Comment: would u please explain in detail what d u want?

Comment: i try to connect to a server with a special uri. within that uri i pass some parameter that I need. the problem is that i can't reach the server... with a computer it does well...

Answer (score 0):

You must encode your parameters with something like:

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("vorname=maria asdf&email=me@mail.com&phone=0786655962&time=1500&date=160914&merk=wollte nachfragen wegem Termin :) tschüss", "utf-8");
String getURL = "http://irgendeinurl.web44.net/index.php?" + query;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me... The parameters are URL encoded before calling this function... You can customize the return value as per your requirement...

Let me know if you want anything more...

```
public class GenericNetworkAction {


        Context context;
        boolean asynch;
        String returnResponse = "Error";
        String parameters = "";
        public GenericNetworkAction(Context passedContext, boolean passedAsynch, String passedParameters) {
            context = passedContext;
            asynch = passedAsynch;
            parameters = passedParameters;

        }

        public void HandleNetworkActivity() {
               String stringUrl = Constants.baseURL;
               stringUrl = stringUrl + parameters;
                ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    if (asynch)
                    new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(stringUrl);
                    else
                        returnResponse = getServerResponse(stringUrl);
                } else {
    //              Toast.makeText(context, 
    //                      context.getResources().getText(R.string.err_network_na), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("Error", "Error connecting to the network");
                    return;
                    }
        }
        private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strArrayUrl) {
                try {
                    return getServerResponse(strArrayUrl[0]);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return "";
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String strResults) {

                returnResponse = strResults;
            }  

            private String getServerResponse(String strUrl) {
                InputStream localInputStream;
                try {
                    URL localUrl = new URL (strUrl);
                    HttpURLConnection localConn = (HttpURLConnection) localUrl.openConnection();
                    localConn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                    localConn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                    localConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    localConn.setDoInput(true);
                    //localConn.setDoOutput(true);
                    localConn.connect();
                    localConn.getErrorStream();

                    int iResponseCode = localConn.getResponseCode();
                    localInputStream = localConn.getErrorStream();

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1000000];
                    int iReturnNoOfBytes, iOffset=0;
                    iReturnNoOfBytes = localInputStream.read(buffer);
                     localConn.disconnect();
                    return new String(buffer);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return "";
            }

        }
        private String getServerResponse(String strUrl) {
            InputStream localInputStream;
            try {
                //strUrl = URLEncoder.encode(strUrl, "UTF-8");
                URL localUrl = new URL (strUrl);
                HttpURLConnection localConn = (HttpURLConnection) localUrl.openConnection();
                localConn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                localConn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                localConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                localConn.setDoInput(true);
                localConn.connect();


                int iResponseCode = localConn.getResponseCode();
                localInputStream = localConn.getInputStream();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1000000];
                int iReturnNoOfBytes, iOffset=0;
                iReturnNoOfBytes = localInputStream.read(buffer);
                 localConn.disconnect();
                 Log.i("query", strUrl);
                return new String(buffer);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add http:// before domain name
Modify url like below..

```
    String getURL = "http://irgendeinurl.web44.net/index.php?vorname=maria      asdf&email=me@mail.com&phone=0786655962&time=1500&date=160914&merk=wollte nachfragen wegem Termin :) tschüss";
```